# Take advantage of Flash CS4's PNG Compression, but as an external file?

Tags: compression, png, flash-cs4, actionscript-3

Here's the issue:  I'm developing some Flash web sites and really enjoying AS3.

**The problem:**  PNG 24-bit images are too big...  I have three PNG images with transparency that I'd like to rotate through on the "Home page" every 10 seconds or so.  Great.  No problem - but instead of embedding all three PNGs in the SWF, which would take the thing longer to load, I'd like to load them dynamically from external files, so that the user doesn't have to wait around for images to load that aren't going to be displayed for another 10-15 seconds anyway.  That's fine...  I have working code for that.

**The real problem:**  These PNG sizes, even loaded from external files on the fly, are really bugging me.  One image is 350k when saved with Photoshop - 300k when I use **PNGOUT**.  But...  when I import the PNG into Flash's Library, I can go in and set it to JPG/Image Compression which reduces the size to about 45k, yet maintains the alpha information!!  If Flash can compress my PNG that much, and still make it look good, why can't I find an app that can do the same for an external file?  I'd be content to load my images into the Flash library and let it handle the compression, but if I end up with 5 or 6 images, that still turns out to be too long of a loading time.

**Summary:**  How can I shrink my 350k PNG image with transparency down to 45k like Flash does when I import it into it's library?

**Possible solution:**  Or.... hmmmm....  this could be a workaround...  maybe I could just make a separate SWF movie for each PNG I want to use which uses the Flash compressed image - then read *that* file dynamically using a Loader...  That ought to work!  *I shall return and report...*

But still, how does Flash compress those PNGs so much more than compressors like PNGOUT?  Maybe I'm just not passing in the right parameters for them to be effective.

Thanks for reading my ramblings.  You all are a great sounding board!

Comment: Hopefully this little excursion could help somebody out with a similar issue.  Using an external SWF file that has the PNG imported and compressed a la Flash does seem to work - I was concerned that a transparent background might be an issue, but after setting the Window Mode in the HTML Publish Settings to Transparent/Windowless, it worked like a charm.

However, any other recommendations would be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

PNG compression is lossless, so it can't compete with lossy perceptual compression schemes as JPEG. Just be sure that your png are the size to be displayed (or not : one trivial "compression" scheme would be to save your image scaled down and zoom it when displaying, but this is normally unsatisfactory). If you can't go below 24-bits (you cant go to a 256-pallete, I guesss) I dont think much can be done. I can only suggest to give a look at [PngCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same question, but later, I think flash used JPEG compress for PNG files. The JPEG-compressed "png" is actually a variant that standard png format does not support, but flash supports. In my own flash project, I used it a lot. I even used swftools to generate an animated SWF from a lot of png, so I can load the single "png gallery" swf and use all the pngs inside.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is a year old, but I thought it would be good for future reference. Using any of the png compression tools (PngCrush, Optipng) will not get anywhere near the same results as Flash compression.

The best way I've found to use flash compression without creating each swf in the Flash IDE is using SwfTools' png2swf utility, it will keep alpha channels and also allow you to set the jpeg's compression quality.

http://www.swftools.org/png2swf.html